# If $g(f(x))$ is continuous if and only if $g$ is continuous, then $f$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : M \rightarrow N$ and $g : N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where M and N are metric spaces. Let $f$ be one to one and onto. Suppose $g$ is continuous if and only if $g\circ f$ is continuous.

I have proven that $f$ is continuous, but I can't figure out how to show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: No I mean that ($g \circ f$ is continuous iff $g$ is continuous) $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is a homeomorphism

Comment: Note that $f^{-1}:N\to M$ and $g\circ f:M\to \mathbb{R}$. Since $g\circ f$ continuous if and only if $(g\circ f)\circ f^{-1}=g$ continuous, $f^{-1}$ is continuous follows by the same argument you have used for $f$.

Comment: Ah thank you a lot!

Comment: @withoutfeather Actually I'm not sure that helps. To prove it for $f$, I used that the distance function on N $d(x, f(x))$ is continuous, so $d\circ f$ is continuous, so if $x_n \rightarrow x$, $d(f(x_n), f(x)) = d\circ f(x_n) \rightarrow d\circ f(x) = d(f(x), f(x)) = 0$ so $d(f(x_n), f(x)) \rightarrow 0$ and so $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$. I can't see how to use what you've suggested in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\theta$ be the metric on $M$ and $x\in N$. Take $g:N\to \mathbb{R}, y\mapsto \theta(f^{-1}(x),f^{-1}(y))$, hence $g\circ f:M\to \mathbb{R}, y\mapsto \theta(f^{-1}(x),y)$ is continuous. So $g$ is continuous, i.e. $f^{-1}$ continuous at $x$.

Comment: +1. A small correction: $x \in N$ not $x \in M$.

Comment: Thank you, edited.

Comment: I fail to see how g being continuous implies the inverse of f is continuous. The metric on M is continuous regardless of the continuity of the inverse of f

Comment: Nevermind I see now